# Solution folder andssmart device deployment projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, cab

Is there possible to organize this type of projects in groups?
I can not move Smart Device Deployment project into Solution folder:

[image: Start dragging]

[image: Dropping]

As result: Setup project ***has not*** moved to destination folder

Comment: Is there possible to organize this type of projects in groups? Yes, it can!

Comment: LOL - questions and answers. Does that mean you figured it out?

Comment: why I can't unload deployment project and I can't move project to solution folder manually in Visual Studio 2008 Solution explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Setup and Deploy project.

I do not have VS2008 here at work anymore, so I am unable to post a VS2008 screenshot.

In VS2010, it looks like this:

[image: setup and deployment]

Hopefully, you have something to select from in the ListView area.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I'm at home with my copy of VS2008.

Are you wanting something like this?

[image: setup and solution]

That is created when you add a new project to your solution (FTMaint in my pic).

If you want to specify where the output of the Setup project goes, Right-Click the Setup project, select Properties, and specify where the output file should go in the Output file name field:

[image: output spec]

Comment: I am working now with Smart Device Setup/Deployment projects. There are following issues: 1) I can't unload project this type 2) I can't move project this type into another Solution Folder

Comment: Is there bug or feature? As I mentioned I should write VS Macro that can programmatically do that. I still hope, that this is still possible. As I commented previously projects this type can be grouped in folders. Only drag-and-drop support in VS 2008 is buggy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is this what you are trying to do? [Project Unavailable in Visual Studio 2010 Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22115102/153923) Someone voted to close it, and it never even got an upvote.

Comment: Me, too! I used VS2008.