# Project Unavailable in Visual Studio 2010 Solution

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I created the tool below to create a VS2010 Solution using existing project folders from our non-Microsoft version control. When the code runs, you tell it what folder your code is in, what folder your solution needs to go to, then accept the solution name to create in the folder you pick.

It was working OK for a while, until I made some changes to allow for multiple Projects within the same Solution, but now it is broken.

[image: broken]

No error messages are thrown, so I am having difficulty isolating what the issue is this time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace solutionBuilderNS {

  class Program {

    private static StreamWriter m_writeText;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string solutionName = null;;
      var properties = Properties.Settings.Default;
      string dataSource = properties.lastFolder;
      string solutionDir = properties.localDir;
      if ((args != null) && (0 < args.Length)) {
        solutionName = args[0];
        if (1 < args.Length) {
          dataSource = args[1];
          if (2 < args.Length) {
            solutionDir = args[2];
          }
        }
      }
      string message = 
        "This will create a Visual Studio Solution.\r\n\r\n" +
        "If you need to save the old file first, do so now.\r\n\r\n" +
        "Are you ready to begin?";
      if (MessageBox.Show(message, "Create Solution " + solutionName, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes) {
        using (var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
          dlg.SelectedPath = dataSource;
          dlg.Description = string.Format("Specify Physical Location of Files:\r\n{0}", dataSource);
          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dataSource = dlg.SelectedPath;
          } else {
            dataSource = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource)) {
        using (var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
          dlg.SelectedPath = solutionDir;
          dlg.Description = string.Format("Specify Folder to Create Solution in:\r\n{0}", solutionDir);
          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            bool buildSlnName = (args != null) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]);
            if (buildSlnName) {
              if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Call Solution '{0}'?", args[0]),
                "Solution Name",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes) {
                  buildSlnName = false;
                  solutionName = args[0];
              }
            }
            if (buildSlnName) {
              solutionDir = dlg.SelectedPath;
              var dir = new DirectoryInfo(solutionDir);
              solutionName = String.Format("{0}_{1}.sln", dir.Parent.Name, dir.Name);
            }
            if (solutionName.IndexOf(".sln") == -1) {
              solutionName += ".sln";
            }
          } else {
            solutionDir = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource)) {
        properties.lastFolder = dataSource;
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(solutionDir)) {
        properties.localDir = solutionDir;
      }
      properties.Save();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(solutionDir)) {
        var logfilePath = Path.Combine(solutionDir, "logfile.txt");
        if (File.Exists(logfilePath)) {
          File.Delete(logfilePath);
        }
        var logfile = new FileInfo(logfilePath);
        using (m_writeText = logfile.AppendText()) {
          var item = new SolutionBuilder(solutionDir, dataSource);
          var startTime = DateTime.Now;
          Program.WriteLine("Solution {0} started at {1:g}", item.Name, startTime);
          item.Generate(solutionName);
          Program.WriteLine("Solution {0} created ({1})\r\n", item.Name, DateTime.Now - startTime);
          item.Start();
          if (item.ErrorsExist) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("The following errors were encountered:\r\n");
            foreach (var error in item.ErrorArray) {
              sb.AppendLine("  " + error);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Handled Errors (skipped)");
          }
          m_writeText.Flush();
          m_writeText.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.\r\nPress any key to close.");
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args) {
      string created = string.Format(text, args);
      m_writeText.WriteLine(created);
    }

  }

  public class SolutionBuilder {

    #region ' CONSTANTS '
    private const string SOLUTION_HEAD = "\r\nMicrosoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00\r\n# Visual Studio 2010\r\n";
    private const string FMT_PLATFORMS =
      "    {0}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86";
    private const string FMT_GLOB_SEC = 
      "Global\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution\r\n" +
      "    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86\r\n" +
          "    Release|x86 = Release|x86\r\n" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution\r\n" +
      "{0}" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution\r\n" +
          "    HideSolutionNode = FALSE\r\n" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
      "EndGlobal";
    #endregion

    private string m_solution;
    private List<string> m_errors;
    private DirectoryInfo m_rootDir, m_network;

    public SolutionBuilder(string rootDir, string networkDir) {
      m_errors = new List<string>();
      m_rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(rootDir);
      m_network = new DirectoryInfo(networkDir);
    }

    public string Name { get { return m_solution; } }

    public string[] ErrorArray {
      get { return m_errors.ToArray(); }
    }

    public bool ErrorsExist {
      get { return (0 < m_errors.Count); }
    }

    public void Generate(string solutionName) {
      m_solution = solutionName;
      if (m_rootDir.Exists) {
        var body = new StringBuilder(SOLUTION_HEAD);
        var fullSolutionName = Path.Combine(m_rootDir.FullName, Name);
        if (File.Exists(fullSolutionName)) {
          Program.WriteLine("Creating backup of Solution {0}...", fullSolutionName);
          var refBackup = fullSolutionName.Replace('.', '_') + ".old";
          if (File.Exists(refBackup)) {
            File.Delete(refBackup);
          }
          File.Move(fullSolutionName, refBackup);
          File.Delete(fullSolutionName);
        }
        var projects = new List<Project>();
        foreach (var subnet in m_network.GetDirectories()) {
          Program.WriteLine(String.Empty);
          var item = new Project(subnet.Name, m_rootDir.FullName);
          item.Generate(Name, subnet.FullName);
          if (item.ErrorsExist) {
            m_errors.AddRange(item.ErrorArray);
          }
          projects.Add(item);
        }
        Program.WriteLine(String.Empty);
        var globalSection = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in projects) {
          var projLine = item.SolutionEntry;
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(projLine)) {
            body.AppendLine(projLine);
            globalSection.AppendLine(string.Format(FMT_PLATFORMS, item.Guid));
          }
        }
        body.AppendLine(string.Format(FMT_GLOB_SEC, globalSection.ToString()));
        var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(m_rootDir.FullName, solutionName));
        using (var sw = file.AppendText()) {
          Program.WriteLine("Saving Solution {0}...", Name);
          sw.Write(body.ToString());
          sw.Flush();
          sw.Close();
        }
      }
    }

    public void Start() {
      var path = Path.Combine(m_rootDir.FullName, m_solution);
      Program.WriteLine("Launching Solution {0}...", Name);
      Process.Start(path);
    }

  }

  public class Project : IComparable<Project>, IEquatable<Project> {

    #region ' CONSTANTS '
    private const string FMT_FOLDER_INCLUDE = "    <Folder Include=\"{0}\" />";
    private const string FMT_CONTENT_INCLUDE =
      "    <Content Include=\"{0}\" >\r\n" +
      "      <Link>{1}</Link>\r\n" +
      "    </Content>";
    private const string FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE =
      "    <Compile Include=\"{0}\" />\r\n";
    private const string FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE_2 =
      "    <Compile Include=\"{0}\" >\r\n" +
      "      <DependentUpon>{1}</DependentUpon>\r\n" +
      "    </Compile>";
    private const string FMT_PROJ_HEAD =
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
      "<Project ToolsVersion=\"4.0\" DefaultTargets=\"Build\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "    <Configuration Condition=\" '$(Configuration)' == '' \">Debug</Configuration>\r\n" +
      "    <Platform Condition=\" '$(Platform)' == '' \">AnyCPU</Platform>\r\n" +
      "    <ProductVersion>1.0.0.0</ProductVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <ProjectGuid>{0}</ProjectGuid>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>\r\n" +
      "    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>\r\n" +
      "    <RootNamespace>{1}_NS</RootNamespace>\r\n" +
      "    <AssemblyName>{1}_ASS</AssemblyName>\r\n" +
      "    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>\r\n" +
      "    <TargetFrameworkProfile />\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>false</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <UseVSHostingProcess>true</UseVSHostingProcess>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' \">\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' \">\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <ItemGroup>\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Configuration\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Core\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Data\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Data.DataSetExtensions\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Drawing\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.EnterpriseServices\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Extensions\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Mobile\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Services\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Xml\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Xml.Linq\" />\r\n" +
      "  </ItemGroup>";
    private const string PROJ_FOOT =
      "  <Import Project=\"$(MSBuildBinPath)\\Microsoft.CSharp.targets\" />\r\n" +
      "  <Import Project=\"$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\v10.0\\WebApplications\\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets\" />\r\n" +
      "  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. \r\n" +
      "      Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.\r\n" +
      "    <Target Name=\"BeforeBuild\"></Target>\r\n" +
      "    <Target Name=\"AfterBuild\"></Target>\r\n" +
      "  -->\r\n</Project>";
    #endregion

    private static string FORBIDDEN;
    private static string[] CODEFILES, LC_EXCLUDES, WEBFILES;
    private int m_trimLeft;
    private string m_guid, m_projName, m_folder;
    private List<string> m_compiles, m_contents, m_errors, m_folders;
    private DirectoryInfo m_network;
    private VsProjectType m_projType, m_fileType;
    public enum CodeTypes { CPP = 0, CS = 1, VB = 2 }
    public enum WebTypes { ASP, ASPX, HTML }

    static Project() {
      CODEFILES = new string[] { ".cpp", ".cs", ".vb" };
      LC_EXCLUDES = new string[] { ".svn", "desktop.ini", "thumbs.db" };
      WEBFILES = new string[] { ".asp", ".aspx", ".html" };
      FORBIDDEN = "~`!@#$%^&*()+|\\\"<>?/";
    }

    public Project(string name, string folder) {
      m_projType = VsProjectType.Unknown;
      m_fileType = VsProjectType.Unknown;
      m_projName = name;
      m_folder = Path.Combine(folder, name);
      m_guid = "{" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
      m_compiles = new List<string>();
      m_contents = new List<string>();
      m_errors = new List<string>();
      m_folders = new List<string>();
      Program.WriteLine("Project {0} started.", Name);
    }

    public string Guid { get { return m_guid; } }

    public string[] ErrorArray {
      get { return m_errors.ToArray(); }
    }

    public bool ErrorsExist {
      get { return (0 < m_errors.Count); }
    }

    public void Generate(string solution, string network) {
      Program.WriteLine("Generating Project {0}...", Name);
      if (!Directory.Exists(m_folder)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(m_folder);
      }
      m_network = new DirectoryInfo(network);
      m_trimLeft = m_network.FullName.Length + 1;
      Map(m_network);
      if ((m_projType != VsProjectType.Unknown) && (m_fileType != VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
        var path = Path.Combine(m_folder, Name) + GuidAssist.ProjectExtension(m_fileType);
        var file = new FileInfo(path);
        Program.WriteLine("Project File: {0}", file.FullName);
        if (file.Exists) {
          var refBackup = Path.Combine(m_folder, string.Format("{0}.old", Name.Replace('.', '_')));
          try {
            if (File.Exists(refBackup)) {
              File.Delete(refBackup);
            }
            file.MoveTo(refBackup);
          } catch (Exception err) {
            m_errors.Add(string.Format("Delete {0} Error: {1}", refBackup, err.Message));
          }
          file = new FileInfo(path);
        }
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add(string.Format(FMT_PROJ_HEAD, Guid, solution));
        if (0 < m_folders.Count) {
          m_folders.Sort();
          list.Add("  <ItemGroup>");
          list.AddRange(m_folders.ToArray());
          list.Add("  </ItemGroup>");
        }
        if (0 < m_contents.Count) {
          m_contents.Sort();
          list.Add("  <ItemGroup>");
          list.AddRange(m_contents.ToArray());
          list.Add("  </ItemGroup>");
        }
        if (0 < m_compiles.Count) {
          m_compiles.Sort();
          list.Add("  <ItemGroup>");
          list.AddRange(m_compiles.ToArray());
          list.Add("  </ItemGroup>");
        }
        list.Add(PROJ_FOOT);
        using (var sw = file.AppendText()) {
          Program.WriteLine("Writing Project {0}", Name);
          foreach (var line in list) {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
          }
          sw.Flush();
          sw.Close();
        }
      } else {
        Program.WriteLine("Project {0} SKIPPED! (Proj={1}; Files={2})", Name, m_projType, m_fileType);
      }
    }

    private void Map(DirectoryInfo dir) {
      Program.WriteLine("  mapping {0}...", dir.FullName);
      var netFullName = dir.FullName;
      bool isRoot = (dir == m_network);
      var relativeDir = !isRoot ? netFullName.Substring(m_trimLeft) : null;
      var subs = dir.GetDirectories();
      if (!isRoot) {
        var physicalDir = Path.Combine(m_folder, relativeDir);
        if (!Directory.Exists(physicalDir)) {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalDir);
        }
        var folder = string.Format(FMT_FOLDER_INCLUDE, relativeDir);
        m_folders.Add(folder);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < subs.Length; i++) {
        DirectoryInfo sub = null;
        try {
          sub = subs[i];
          if (!LC_EXCLUDES.Contains(sub.Name.ToLower()) && !Offensive(sub.Name)) {
            Map(sub);
          }
        } catch (Exception err) {
          m_errors.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", err.GetType(), err.Message));
        }
      }
      if (!isRoot) {
        var files = dir.GetFiles();
        var compiles = new List<string>();
        var contents = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
          FileInfo file = null;
          try {
            file = files[i];
            var name = file.Name.ToLower();
            if (!LC_EXCLUDES.Contains(name) && !Offensive(name)) {
              var ext = file.Extension.ToLower();
              if ((m_fileType == VsProjectType.Unknown) || (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
                if (WEBFILES.Contains(ext) && (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.WebSite;
                }
                if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.CPP]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsCpp;
                } else if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.CS]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsCs;
                } else if (ext == ".php") {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.PHP;
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.WebApplication;
                } else if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.VB]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsVb;
                }
              }
              if (((m_fileType == VsProjectType.WindowsCs) || (m_fileType == VsProjectType.WindowsVb)) &&
                ((m_projType == VsProjectType.WebSite) || (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown))) {
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.WebApplication;
              }
              var link = Path.Combine(relativeDir, file.Name);
              if (CODEFILES.Contains(ext)) {
                compiles.Add(link);
              } else {
                contents.Add(link);
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception err) {
            m_errors.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", err.GetType(), err.Message));
          }
        }
        compiles.Sort();
        contents.Sort();
        foreach (var link in contents) {
          m_contents.Add(string.Format(FMT_CONTENT_INCLUDE, link, link));
        }
        foreach (var link in compiles) {
          try {
            var value = contents.First(item => (-1 < link.IndexOf(item)));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
              m_compiles.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE_2, link, value));
            } else {
              m_compiles.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE, link));
            }
          } catch (Exception) {
            m_compiles.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE, link));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public string Name { get { return m_projName; } }

    private bool Offensive(string name) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
        foreach (char c in name) {
          if (-1 < FORBIDDEN.IndexOf(c)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    public string SolutionEntry {
      get {
        if ((m_projType != VsProjectType.Unknown) && (m_fileType != VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
          return string.Format("Project(\"{0}\") = \"{1}\", \"{1}\\{1}{2}\", \"{3}\"\r\nEndProject",
            GuidAssist.ProjectGuid(m_projType), Name, GuidAssist.ProjectExtension(m_fileType), Guid);
        }
        return null;
      }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Project other) {
      return Guid.CompareTo(other.Guid);
    }

    public bool Equals(Project other) {
      return Guid.Equals(other.Guid);
    }

  }

  public enum VsProjectType {
    WindowsCs, WindowsVb, WindowsCpp,
    WebApplication, WebSite,
    DistributedSystem, WCF, WPF,
    VisualDbTools, Db, DbOther,
    Test,
    LegacySmartDeviceCs, LegacySmartDeviceVb,
    SmartDeviceCs, SmartDeviceVb,
    WorkflowCs, WorkflowVb,
    DeploymentMergeMod, DeploymentCab, DeploymentSetup, DeploymentSmartDeviceCab,
    VsToolsForApps, VsToolsForOffice,
    SharePointWorkflow,
    XnaWindows, XnaZbox, ZnaZune,
    SharePointVb, SharePointCs,
    Silverlight,
    AspNetMvc1, AspNetMvc2, AspNetMvc3, AspNetMvc4,
    Extensibility,
    PHP,
    Unknown=-1
  }

  public class GuidAssist {

    private static List<string> m_guidList;

    static GuidAssist() {
      m_guidList = new List<string>();
      m_guidList.AddRange(new string[] {
        "{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}", "{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}", "{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}",
        "{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}", "{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}",
        "{F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}", "{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}", "{60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}",
        "{C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}", "{A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}", "{4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}",
        "{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}",
        "{20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}", "{CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}",
        "{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}", "{68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}",
        "{14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}", "{D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}",
        "{06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}", "{3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}", "{978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}", "{AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}",
        "{A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}", "{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}",
        "{F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}",
        "{6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}", "{2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}", "{D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}",
        "{EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}", "{593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}",
        "{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}",
        "{603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}", "{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}", "{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}", "{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}",
        "{82B43B9B-A64C-4715-B499-D71E9CA2BD60}",
        "{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}",
        "-1"
      });
    }

    public static string ProjectGuid(VsProjectType projectType) {
      return m_guidList[(int)projectType];
    }

    public static string ProjectExtension(VsProjectType projectType) {
      switch (projectType) {
        case VsProjectType.LegacySmartDeviceCs:
        case VsProjectType.SharePointCs:
        case VsProjectType.SmartDeviceCs:
        case VsProjectType.WindowsCs:
        case VsProjectType.WorkflowCs:
          return ".csproj";
        case VsProjectType.LegacySmartDeviceVb:
        case VsProjectType.SharePointVb:
        case VsProjectType.SmartDeviceVb:
        case VsProjectType.WindowsVb:
        case VsProjectType.WorkflowVb:
          return ".vbproj";
        case VsProjectType.WindowsCpp:
          return ".cppproj";
        case VsProjectType.PHP:
          return ".phpproj";
        default:
          return ".proj";
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Feel free to take the text of this code above, create a new-blank Console Application, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all of the text in the file **Program.cs**, and paste my text right in there.

To use it, you will need to add a Settings section to your Solution's Properties page, then add the two strings 'lastFolder' and 'localDir'.

The included mini-class I wrote called `GuidAssist` uses actual Microsoft Codes for the different types of projects defined in the enumerated `VsProjectType` types I have created.

I would love for someone else to get some use out of this besides myself, but I need to get it working first.

Comment: I see a vote for close. Why? Originally, I had this posted on Code Review. They closed it and said it belonged here. If it gets closed here, then someone at **Stack Exchange** needs to start coordinating the various sites better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace spiderBuilderNS {

  class Program {

    private static StreamWriter m_writeText;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string solnName = null; // "spider_e_www_iis.sln";
      var properties = Properties.Settings.Default;
      string dataDir = properties.lastFolder;
      string solnDir = properties.localDir;
      if ((args != null) && (0 < args.Length)) {
        solnName = args[0];
        if (1 < args.Length) {
          dataDir = args[1];
          if (2 < args.Length) {
            solnDir = args[2];
          }
        }
      }
      string message = 
        "This will create a Visual Studio Solution.\r\n\r\n" +
        "If you need to save the old file first, do so now.\r\n\r\n" +
        "Are you ready to begin?";
      if (MessageBox.Show(message, "Create Solution " + solnName, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes) {
        using (var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
          dlg.SelectedPath = dataDir;
          dlg.Description = string.Format("Specify Physical Location of Files:\r\n{0}", dataDir);
          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dataDir = dlg.SelectedPath;
          } else {
            dataDir = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataDir)) {
        using (var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
          dlg.SelectedPath = solnDir;
          dlg.Description = string.Format("Specify Folder to Create Solution in:\r\n{0}", solnDir);
          if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            bool buildSlnName = (args != null) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]);
            if (buildSlnName) {
              if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Call Solution '{0}'?", args[0]),
                "Solution Name",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Yes) {
                  buildSlnName = false;
                  solnName = args[0];
              }
            }
            if (buildSlnName) {
              solnDir = dlg.SelectedPath;
              var dir = new DirectoryInfo(solnDir);
              solnName = String.Format("{0}_{1}.sln", dir.Parent.Name, dir.Name);
            }
            if (solnName.IndexOf(".sln") == -1) {
              solnName += ".sln";
            }
          } else {
            solnDir = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataDir)) {
        properties.lastFolder = dataDir;
      }
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(solnDir)) {
        properties.localDir = solnDir;
      }
      properties.Save();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(solnDir)) {
        var logfilePath = Path.Combine(solnDir, "logfile.txt");
        if (File.Exists(logfilePath)) {
          File.Delete(logfilePath);
        }
        var logfile = new FileInfo(logfilePath);
        using (m_writeText = logfile.AppendText()) {
          var item = new SolutionBuilder(solnDir, dataDir);
          var startTime = DateTime.Now;
          Program.WriteLine("Solution {0} started at {1:g}", item.Name, startTime);
          item.Generate(solnName);
          Program.WriteLine("Solution {0} created ({1})\r\n", item.Name, DateTime.Now - startTime);
          item.Start();
          if (item.ErrorsExist) {
            var sb = new StringBuilder("The following errors were encountered:\r\n");
            foreach (var error in item.ErrorArray) {
              sb.AppendLine("  " + error);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Handled Errors (skipped)");
          }
          m_writeText.Flush();
          m_writeText.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done.\r\nPress any key to close.");
        Console.ReadKey();
      }
    }

    public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args) {
      string created = string.Format(text, args);
      m_writeText.WriteLine(created);
    }

  }

  public class SolutionBuilder {

    #region ' CONSTANTS '
    private const string SOLUTION_HEAD = "\r\nMicrosoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00\r\n# Visual Studio 2010\r\n";
    private const string FMT_PLATFORMS =
      "    {0}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86\r\n" +
      "    {0}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86";
    private const string FMT_GLOB_SEC = 
      "Global\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution\r\n" +
      "    Debug|x86 = Debug|x86\r\n" +
          "    Release|x86 = Release|x86\r\n" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution\r\n" +
      "{0}" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
        "  GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution\r\n" +
          "    HideSolutionNode = FALSE\r\n" +
        "  EndGlobalSection\r\n" +
      "EndGlobal";
    #endregion

    private string m_solnName;
    private List<string> m_errors;
    private DirectoryInfo m_solnDir, m_dataDir;

    public SolutionBuilder(string solnDir, string dataDir) {
      m_errors = new List<string>();
      m_solnDir = new DirectoryInfo(solnDir);
      m_dataDir = new DirectoryInfo(dataDir);
    }

    public string Name { get { return m_solnName; } }

    public string[] ErrorArray {
      get { return m_errors.ToArray(); }
    }

    public bool ErrorsExist {
      get { return (0 < m_errors.Count); }
    }

    public void Generate(string solnName) {
      m_solnName = solnName;
      if (m_solnDir.Exists) {
        var body = new StringBuilder(SOLUTION_HEAD);
        var fullSolutionName = Path.Combine(m_solnDir.FullName, Name);
        if (File.Exists(fullSolutionName)) {
          Program.WriteLine("Creating backup of Solution {0}...", fullSolutionName);
          var refBackup = fullSolutionName.Replace('.', '_') + ".old";
          if (File.Exists(refBackup)) {
            File.Delete(refBackup);
          }
          File.Move(fullSolutionName, refBackup);
          File.Delete(fullSolutionName);
        }
        var projects = new List<Project>();
        foreach (var sub in m_dataDir.GetDirectories()) {
          Program.WriteLine(String.Empty);
          var projDir = Path.Combine(m_solnDir.FullName, sub.Name);
          var item = new Project(projDir, sub.FullName);
          item.Generate(sub.Name);
          if (item.ErrorsExist) {
            m_errors.AddRange(item.ErrorArray);
          }
          projects.Add(item);
        }
        Program.WriteLine(String.Empty);
        var globalSection = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in projects) {
          var projLine = item.SolutionEntry;
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(projLine)) {
            body.AppendLine(projLine);
            globalSection.AppendLine(string.Format(FMT_PLATFORMS, item.Guid));
          }
        }
        body.AppendLine(string.Format(FMT_GLOB_SEC, globalSection.ToString()));
        var file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(m_solnDir.FullName, solnName));
        using (var sw = file.AppendText()) {
          Program.WriteLine("Saving Solution {0}...", Name);
          sw.Write(body.ToString());
          sw.Flush();
          sw.Close();
        }
      }
    }

    public void Start() {
      var path = Path.Combine(m_solnDir.FullName, m_solnName);
      Program.WriteLine("Launching Solution {0}...", Name);
      Process.Start(path);
    }

  }

  public class Project : IComparable<Project>, IEquatable<Project> {

    #region ' CONSTANTS '
    private const string FMT_FOLDER_INCLUDE =
      "    <Folder Include=\"{0}\" />";
    private const string FMT_CONTENT_INCLUDE =
      "    <Content Include=\"{0}\" >\r\n" +
      "      <Link>{1}</Link>\r\n" +
      "    </Content>";
    private const string FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE =
      "    <Compile Include=\"{0}\" />\r\n";
    private const string FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE_2 =
      "    <Compile Include=\"{0}\" >\r\n" +
      "      <DependentUpon>{1}</DependentUpon>\r\n" +
      "    </Compile>";
    private const string FMT_PROJ_HEAD =
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
      "<Project ToolsVersion=\"4.0\" DefaultTargets=\"Build\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "    <Configuration Condition=\" '$(Configuration)' == '' \">Debug</Configuration>\r\n" +
      "    <Platform Condition=\" '$(Platform)' == '' \">AnyCPU</Platform>\r\n" +
      "    <ProductVersion>1.0.0.0</ProductVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <ProjectGuid>{0}</ProjectGuid>\r\n" +
      "    <ProjectTypeGuids>{1};{2}</ProjectTypeGuids>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>\r\n" +
      "    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>\r\n" +
      "    <RootNamespace>{3}_NS</RootNamespace>\r\n" +
      "    <AssemblyName>{3}_ASS</AssemblyName>\r\n" +
      "    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>\r\n" +
      "    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>\r\n" +
      "    <TargetFrameworkProfile />\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>false</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <UseVSHostingProcess>true</UseVSHostingProcess>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' \">\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' \">\r\n" +
      "    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Debug\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>full</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64' \">\r\n" +
      "    <OutputPath>bin\\Release\\</OutputPath>\r\n" +
      "    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>\r\n" +
      "    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>\r\n" +
      "    <Optimize>true</Optimize>\r\n" +
      "    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>\r\n" +
      "    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>\r\n" +
      "    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <ItemGroup>\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Configuration\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Core\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Data\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Data.DataSetExtensions\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Drawing\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.EnterpriseServices\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Extensions\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Mobile\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Web.Services\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Xml\" />\r\n" +
      "    <Reference Include=\"System.Xml.Linq\" />\r\n" +
      "  </ItemGroup>";
    private const string FMT_PHP_HEAD =
      "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n" +
      "<Project ToolsVersion=\"4.0\" DefaultTargets=\"Build\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003\">\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "    <Configuration Condition=\" '$(Configuration)' == '' \">Debug</Configuration>\r\n" +
      "    <Name>PHPWebProject2</Name>\r\n" +
      "    <ProjectGuid>{0}</ProjectGuid>\r\n" +
      "    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>\r\n" +
      "    <RootNamespace>PHPWebProject2</RootNamespace>\r\n" +
      "    <!-- important to be opened by PHP Tools, when also Phalanger Tools are installed -->\r\n" +
      "    <ProjectTypeGuids>{1}</ProjectTypeGuids>\r\n" +
      "    <AssemblyName>{2}</AssemblyName>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' \">\r\n" +
      "    <IncludeDebugInformation>true</IncludeDebugInformation>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>\r\n" +
      "  <PropertyGroup Condition=\" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' \">\r\n" +
      "    <IncludeDebugInformation>false</IncludeDebugInformation>\r\n" +
      "  </PropertyGroup>";
    private const string ITEM_GRP_START = "  <ItemGroup>";
    private const string ITEM_GRP_STOP = "  </ItemGroup>";
    private const string PROJ_FOOT =
      "  <Import Project=\"$(MSBuildBinPath)\\Microsoft.CSharp.targets\" />\r\n" +
      "  <Import Project=\"$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\v10.0\\WebApplications\\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets\" />\r\n" +
      "  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. \r\n" +
      "      Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.\r\n" +
      "    <Target Name=\"BeforeBuild\"></Target>\r\n" +
      "    <Target Name=\"AfterBuild\"></Target>\r\n" +
      "  -->\r\n</Project>";
    private const string PHP_FOOT = "</Project>";
    private const string PHPTOOLS_GUID = "{A0786B88-2ADB-4C21-ABE8-AA2D79766269}";
    #endregion

    private static string FORBIDDEN;
    private static string[] CODEFILES, LC_EXCLUDES, WEBFILES;
    private int m_trimLeft;
    private string m_guid, m_projName, m_projDir, m_dataDir;
    private List<string> m_compiles, m_contents, m_errors, m_folders;
    private VsProjectType m_projType, m_fileType;
    public enum CodeTypes { CPP = 0, CS = 1, VB = 2 }
    public enum WebTypes { ASP, ASPX, HTML }

    static Project() {
      CODEFILES = new string[] { ".cpp", ".cs", ".vb" };
      LC_EXCLUDES = new string[] { ".svn", "desktop.ini", "thumbs.db" };
      WEBFILES = new string[] { ".asp", ".aspx", ".html" };
      FORBIDDEN = "~`!@#$%^&*()+|\\\"<>?/";
    }

    public Project(string projDir, string dataDir) {
      m_projType = VsProjectType.Unknown;
      m_fileType = VsProjectType.Unknown;
      m_compiles = new List<string>();
      m_contents = new List<string>();
      m_errors = new List<string>();
      m_folders = new List<string>();
      m_projDir = projDir;
      m_dataDir = dataDir;
      m_trimLeft = dataDir.Length + 1;
      m_guid = "{" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
      Program.WriteLine("Project {0} started.", Name);
    }

    public string Guid { get { return m_guid; } }

    public string[] ErrorArray {
      get { return m_errors.ToArray(); }
    }

    public bool ErrorsExist {
      get { return (0 < m_errors.Count); }
    }

    public void Generate(string projName) {
      m_projName = projName;
      Program.WriteLine("Generating Project {0}...", Name);
      if (!Directory.Exists(m_projDir)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(m_projDir);
      }
      Map(new DirectoryInfo(m_dataDir));
      if ((m_projType != VsProjectType.Unknown) && (m_fileType != VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
        var projFullName = Path.Combine(m_projDir, Name) + GuidAssist.ProjectExtension(m_fileType);
        Program.WriteLine("Project File: {0}", projFullName);
        if (File.Exists(projFullName)) {
          var refBackup = Path.Combine(m_projDir, string.Format("{0}.old", Name.Replace('.', '_')));
          try {
            if (File.Exists(refBackup)) {
              File.Delete(refBackup);
            }
            File.Move(projFullName, refBackup);
          } catch (Exception err) {
            m_errors.Add(string.Format("Delete {0} Error: {1}", refBackup, err.Message));
          }
        }
        var list = new List<string>();
        if (m_projType != VsProjectType.PHP) {
          list.Add(string.Format(FMT_PROJ_HEAD, Guid, GuidAssist.ProjectGuid(m_projType), GuidAssist.ProjectGuid(m_fileType), projName)); // Non-PHP
        } else {
          list.Add(string.Format(FMT_PHP_HEAD, Guid, PHPTOOLS_GUID, projName));
        }
        if (0 < m_folders.Count) {
          m_folders.Sort();
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_START);
          foreach (var link in m_folders) {
            list.Add(string.Format(FMT_FOLDER_INCLUDE, link));
          }
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_STOP);
        }
        if (0 < m_contents.Count) {
          m_contents.Sort();
          m_contents.Sort();
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_START);
          foreach (var link in m_contents) {
            list.Add(string.Format(FMT_CONTENT_INCLUDE, link, link));
          }
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_STOP);
        }
        if (0 < m_compiles.Count) {
          m_compiles.Sort();
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_START);
          m_compiles.Sort();
          foreach (var link in m_compiles) {
            try {
              var value = m_compiles.First(item => (-1 < link.IndexOf(item)));
              if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
                list.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE_2, link, value));
              } else {
                list.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE, link));
              }
            } catch (Exception) {
              list.Add(string.Format(FMT_COMPILE_INCLUDE, link));
            }
          }
          list.Add(ITEM_GRP_STOP);
        }
        if (m_projType != VsProjectType.PHP) {
          list.Add(PROJ_FOOT);
        } else {
          list.Add(PHP_FOOT);
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(projFullName, list.ToArray());
      } else {
        Program.WriteLine("Project {0} was SKIPPED! (Proj={1}; Files={2})", Name, m_projType, m_fileType);
      }
    }

    private void Map(DirectoryInfo dir) {
      Program.WriteLine("  mapping {0}...", dir.FullName);
      var netFullName = dir.FullName;
      bool isRoot = (netFullName == m_dataDir);
      var relativeDir = !isRoot ? netFullName.Substring(m_trimLeft) : null;
      var subs = dir.GetDirectories();
      if (!isRoot) {
        var physicalDir = Path.Combine(m_projDir, relativeDir);
        if (!Directory.Exists(physicalDir)) {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalDir);
        }
        m_folders.Add(relativeDir);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < subs.Length; i++) {
        DirectoryInfo sub = null;
        try {
          sub = subs[i];
          if (!LC_EXCLUDES.Contains(sub.Name.ToLower()) && !Offensive(sub.Name)) {
            Map(sub);
          }
        } catch (Exception err) {
          m_errors.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", err.GetType(), err.Message));
        }
      }
      if (!isRoot) {
        var files = dir.GetFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
          FileInfo file = null;
          try {
            file = files[i];
            var name = file.Name.ToLower();
            if (!LC_EXCLUDES.Contains(name) && !Offensive(name)) {
              var ext = file.Extension.ToLower();
              if ((m_fileType == VsProjectType.Unknown) || (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
                if (WEBFILES.Contains(ext) && (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.WebSite;
                }
                if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.CPP]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsCpp;
                } else if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.CS]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsCs;
                } else if (ext == ".php") {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.PHP;
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.PHP;
                } else if (ext == CODEFILES[(int)CodeTypes.VB]) {
                  m_fileType = VsProjectType.WindowsVb;
                }
              }
              if (((m_fileType == VsProjectType.WindowsCs) || (m_fileType == VsProjectType.WindowsVb)) &&
                ((m_projType == VsProjectType.WebSite) || (m_projType == VsProjectType.Unknown))) {
                  m_projType = VsProjectType.WebApplication;
              }
              var link = Path.Combine(relativeDir, file.Name);
              if (CODEFILES.Contains(ext)) {
                m_compiles.Add(link);
              } else {
                m_contents.Add(link);
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception err) {
            m_errors.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", err.GetType(), err.Message));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public string Name { get { return m_projName; } }

    private bool Offensive(string name) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
        foreach (char c in name) {
          if (-1 < FORBIDDEN.IndexOf(c)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    public string SolutionEntry {
      get {
        if ((m_projType != VsProjectType.Unknown) && (m_fileType != VsProjectType.Unknown)) {
          return string.Format("Project(\"{0}\") = \"{1}\", \"{1}\\{1}{2}\", \"{3}\"\r\nEndProject",
            GuidAssist.ProjectGuid(m_projType), Name, GuidAssist.ProjectExtension(m_fileType), Guid);
        }
        return null;
      }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Project other) {
      return Guid.CompareTo(other.Guid);
    }

    public bool Equals(Project other) {
      return Guid.Equals(other.Guid);
    }

  }

  public enum VsProjectType {
    WindowsCs, WindowsVb, WindowsCpp,
    WebApplication, WebSite,
    DistributedSystem, WCF, WPF,
    VisualDbTools, Db, DbOther,
    Test,
    LegacySmartDeviceCs, LegacySmartDeviceVb,
    SmartDeviceCs, SmartDeviceVb,
    WorkflowCs, WorkflowVb,
    DeploymentMergeMod, DeploymentCab, DeploymentSetup, DeploymentSmartDeviceCab,
    VsToolsForApps, VsToolsForOffice,
    SharePointWorkflow,
    XnaWindows, XnaZbox, ZnaZune,
    SharePointVb, SharePointCs,
    Silverlight,
    AspNetMvc1, AspNetMvc2, AspNetMvc3, AspNetMvc4,
    Extensibility,
    PHP,
    Unknown=-1
  }

  public class GuidAssist {

    private static List<string> m_guidList;

    static GuidAssist() {
      m_guidList = new List<string>();
      m_guidList.AddRange(new string[] {
        "{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}", "{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}", "{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}",
        "{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}", "{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}",
        "{F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}", "{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}", "{60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}",
        "{C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}", "{A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}", "{4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}",
        "{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}",
        "{20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}", "{CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}",
        "{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}", "{68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}",
        "{14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}", "{D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}",
        "{06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}", "{3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}", "{978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}", "{AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}",
        "{A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}", "{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}",
        "{F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}",
        "{6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}", "{2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}", "{D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}",
        "{EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}", "{593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}",
        "{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}",
        "{603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}", "{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}", "{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}", "{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}",
        "{82B43B9B-A64C-4715-B499-D71E9CA2BD60}",
        "{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}",
        "-1"
      });
    }

    public static string ProjectGuid(VsProjectType projectType) {
      return m_guidList[(int)projectType];
    }

    public static string ProjectExtension(VsProjectType projectType) {
      switch (projectType) {
        case VsProjectType.LegacySmartDeviceCs:
        case VsProjectType.SharePointCs:
        case VsProjectType.SmartDeviceCs:
        case VsProjectType.WindowsCs:
        case VsProjectType.WorkflowCs:
          return ".csproj";
        case VsProjectType.LegacySmartDeviceVb:
        case VsProjectType.SharePointVb:
        case VsProjectType.SmartDeviceVb:
        case VsProjectType.WindowsVb:
        case VsProjectType.WorkflowVb:
          return ".vbproj";
        case VsProjectType.WindowsCpp:
          return ".cppproj";
        case VsProjectType.PHP:
          return ".phpproj";
        default:
          return ".proj";
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to do this using the code I have donated:

- Create a console application in Visual Studio
- Right-Click the solution, click Properties, go to the Settings tab
- Select the link to add a new Settings page
- Add the following folders:

  1. `lastFolder`, typeof(String)
  2. `localDir`, typeof(String)

*User Scope* is fine, and no values are required because they will be created when you first run it. It will be helpful next time so you don't have to drill down to the solution every time.

Creating the PHP solutions will work, but to get them to load up in Visual Studio, you'll need [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.devsense.com/doc/phptools).